# why deadlock occures when insert?

Tags: mysql

Confused about deadlock where execute inserting,while I seem to have hold the same lock before.

Mysql5.6,Innodb engin,Read Commited.

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_test` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `md_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `data` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
insert into tb_test (user_id) values (0);
Here are how deadlock happens:
tx1:start transaction;
tx1:SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE user_id = 0 FOR UPDATE;
tx2:start transaction;
tx2:SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE user_id = 0 FOR UPDATE;//blocking
tx1:insert into tb_test (user_id) values (0) on duplicate key update name = 'name';////deadlock occurs
```

I think tx1 acquired the X lock on index user_id with value 0 a`enter code here`fter execute the first sql,and tx2 is blocking,why tx1 get deadlock where try to aquire the same X lock already acquired?Please help.

The deadlock log is:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-03-27 10:01:34 0x560
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 176686, ACTIVE 3 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 791, OS thread handle 13064, query id 16596 127.0.0.1 root Statistics
SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE user_id = 0 FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1067 page no 4 n bits 72 index user_id of table `test`.`tb_test` trx id 176686 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 176685, ACTIVE 3 sec inserting, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 790, OS thread handle 1376, query id 16597 127.0.0.1 root Update
insert into tb_test (user_id) values (0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME = '1'
#SELECT * FROM tb_test WHERE user_id = 0 LOCK IN SHARE MODE
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 1067 page no 4 n bits 72 index user_id of table `test`.`tb_test` trx id 176685 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 1067 page no 4 n bits 72 index user_id of table `test`.`tb_test` trx id 176685 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 2 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;;
 1: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Isn't it the same the lock tx2 is holding and the one it is waiting for?

Comment: please `SHOW ENGINE INNODB` transaction status after each step. What do you hope to achieve with this answer? Handling deadlocks in your application is needed like all other SQL errors thrown.

Comment: I am confused about this deadlock,and want to know why this happens.

Comment: The show engine innodb deadlock log is appended on the question.

Answer (score 0):

tx1 failed because the update status is really happening and tx2 has an intent lock.

Take a look at [SELECT * FROM performance_schema.data_locks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-perfschema-excerpt/8.0/en/data-locks-table.html) at each stage of your transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but intent lock should be compatible with row lock,and tx1 has already held the row lock on user_id 0,so tx1 should not be blocked when acquiring row lock on user_id 0.I have tried to change tx1 sql "insert" to "update",and this succeeded.Why "insert" fails where "update" succeed? I am very confused,can you help me with that.Thank you very much.